# Double Type formatter in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller

I have Model Class of Type **Mileage** That is declared as the following

```
public class Mileage extends Entity {
    @JsonProperty("mileageValue")
    private double mileageValue;

    @JsonProperty("mileageTime")
    private long mileageTime;
}
```

and the Code of the REST Controller method is as the following

```
  public ResponseEntity<Mileage> getMileage(@RequestBody GetRequest req) throws Exception {
        Mileage m1 = new Mileage();
        m1.setMileageTime(10);
        m1.setMileageValue(11111.11111);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(m1, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

As you see the mileageValue property is set to Double, when i use this line

```
m1.setMileageTime(10.0);
```

The repsonse in swagger will be like that

```
 {
  "mileageValue": 11111.11111,
  "mileageTime": 10
}
```

As you Can see the Deicmal Point with zero on its left has been trimmed and became like 10 instead of 10.0, is there a way to make it appears like 10.0 without formatting it as a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code which you have mentioned won't compile it expects long and you are passing it as double.

Please find my solution below:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
    public Mileage test() {
        Mileage m1 = new Mileage();
        m1.setMileageTime(10.0);
        m1.setMileageValue(11111.11111);
        return m1;
    }

    static class Mileage  {

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @JsonProperty("mileageValue")
        private double mileageValue;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @JsonProperty("mileageTime")
        @JsonSerialize(using = DecimalJsonSerializer.class)
        private double mileageTime;
    }

    static class DecimalJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jgen.writeString( String.format("%.2f", value));
        }
    }
```

Response:

```
{
    "mileageValue": 11111.11111,
    "mileageTime": "10.00"
}
```

Linked Issue:

[Why is Double with zero decimal value is omitted during jackson serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134042/why-is-double-with-zero-decimal-value-is-omitted-during-jackson-serialization)